# Select tag inheritance in Jade template

Tags: pug

I have a Jade template, called `options.jade` that contains options for a select tag:

```
block select
  option volvo
  option saab
  option mercedes
  option audi
```

I have additional jade templates where I would like to use this select options template. How can I use `options.jade` in other templates? I was trying something like this in another jade tempalte file:

```
extends options.jade

doctype 5

html
  p Some text.
  body
    block append select
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `include` to allow you to insert the contents of one template into another, for example:

```
// partials/options.jade
select
  option volvo
  option saab
  option mercedes
  option audi

// other templates
doctype html
html
  body
    h3 Select Box
    include partials/options
```